# Error while calling DiscoveryClient.GetAsync connect token endpoint

Tags: identityserver4

We have deployed the identity server4 as a aws serverless lambda function. But when we are calling the base authorize url from code(while creating token for client) getting the forbidden error. Here is the code:

```
[HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string client, string secret)
    {

        IActionResult result = null;

        //discover endpoints from metadata



        var disco = await DiscoveryClient.GetAsync("https://hide-for-security-reasons/prod/");



        if (disco.IsError)
        {
            result = NotFound(disco.Error);

            return result;
        }
        //request token

        var tokenClient = new TokenClient(disco.TokenEndpoint, client, secret);

        var tokenResponse = await tokenClient.RequestClientCredentialsAsync(scope: "sup");

        if (tokenResponse.IsError)
        {
            result = NotFound(tokenResponse.Error);
        }

        result = Ok(tokenResponse.Json);

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: What is the exact response you get and what do the logs for IDS4 say?

Comment: Yes, without providing specific log information it can be everything.

Comment: Problem has been resolved, actually after deploy the lambda function, we have "Prod" suffix in the url and we are trying with "prod" lowercase so that forbidden exception throws.